# Prestashop price display

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, price

It's about Prestashop 1.6. I have a problem with displaying prices on product pages. All the time I was shown the gross price and next, in smaller letters the same price only that I write for items. Is there any possibility that I would automatically attribute only one price to me? I do not want to manually remove the price per item from each product.

{if ($product->show_price && !isset($restricted_country_mode)) || isset($groups) || $product->reference || (isset($HOOK_PRODUCT_ACTIONS) && $HOOK_PRODUCT_ACTIONS)}
        
        quantity > 0} class="hidden"{/if} action="{$link->getPageLink('cart')|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" method="post">
            
            
                
                id|intval}" id="product_page_product_id" />

{if $product->show_price && !isset($restricted_country_mode) && !$PS_CATALOG_MODE}
                        
                        
                            
                                {if $product->quantity > 0}{/if}
                                {if $priceDisplay >= 0 && $priceDisplay <= 2}
                                    {convertPrice price=$productPrice}
                                    
                                    iso_code}" />
                                    {hook h="displayProductPriceBlock" product=$product type="price"}
                                {/if}
                            
                            specificPrice || $product->specificPrice.reduction_type != 'percentage'} style="display:none;"{/if}>
                                
                                    {if $product->specificPrice && $product->specificPrice.reduction_type == 'percentage'}-{$product->specificPrice.reduction*100}%{/if}
                                
                            
                            specificPrice || $product->specificPrice.reduction_type != 'amount' || $product->specificPrice.reduction|floatval ==0} style="display:none"{/if}>
                                
                                {if $product->specificPrice && $product->specificPrice.reduction_type == 'amount' && $product->specificPrice.reduction|floatval !=0}
                                    -{convertPrice price=$productPriceWithoutReduction-$productPrice|floatval}
                                {/if}
                                
                            
                            specificPrice || !$product->specificPrice.reduction) && $group_reduction == 0} class="hidden"{/if}>
                                {if $priceDisplay >= 0 && $priceDisplay <= 2}
                                    {hook h="displayProductPriceBlock" product=$product type="old_price"}
                                    {if $productPriceWithoutReduction > $productPrice}{convertPrice price=$productPriceWithoutReduction}{/if}
                                    
                                {/if}
                            
                            {if $priceDisplay == 2}
                                
                                
                                    {convertPrice price=$product->getPrice(false, $smarty.const.NULL)}
                                    {l s='tax excl.'}
                                
                            {/if}
                         
                        {if $packItems|@count && $productPrice < $product->getNoPackPrice()}
                            
                                {l s='Instead of'} 
                                {convertPrice price=$product->getNoPackPrice()}
                            
                        {/if}
                        {if $product->ecotax != 0}
                            
                                {l s='Including'}
                                {if $priceDisplay == 2}{$ecotax_tax_exc|convertAndFormatPrice}{else}{$ecotax_tax_inc|convertAndFormatPrice}{/if} 
                                {l s='for ecotax'}
                                {if $product->specificPrice && $product->specificPrice.reduction}
                                
{l s='(not impacted by the discount)'}
                                {/if}
                            
                        {/if}
                        {if !empty($product->unity) && $product->unit_price_ratio > 0.000000}
                            {math equation="pprice / punit_price"  pprice=$productPrice  punit_price=$product->unit_price_ratio assign=unit_price}
                            
                                {convertPrice price=$unit_price} 
                                {l s='per'} {$product->unity|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}
                            
                            {hook h="displayProductPriceBlock" product=$product type="unit_price"}
                        {/if}
                    {/if} 
                    {*close if for show price*}
                    {hook h="displayProductPriceBlock" product=$product type="weight"}
                    
                 
                
                    
                    {if !$PS_CATALOG_MODE}
                        quantity <= 0) || !$product->available_for_order || $PS_CATALOG_MODE} style="display: none;"{/if}>
                            {l s='Quantity'}
                            minimal_quantity > 1}{$product->minimal_quantity}{else}1{/if}{/if}" />
                            
                                
                                    
                                
                            
                            
                                
                                    
                                 
                            
                            
                        
                    {/if}
                    
                    minimal_quantity <= 1 || !$product->available_for_order || $PS_CATALOG_MODE} style="display: none;"{/if}>
                        {l s='This product is not sold individually. You must select at least'} 
                        {$product->minimal_quantity} 
                        {l s='quantity for this product.'}
                    
                    {if isset($groups)}
                        
                        
                            
                            {foreach from=$groups key=id_attribute_group item=group}
                                {if $group.attributes|@count}
                                    
                                        {$group.name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'} 
                                        {assign var="groupName" value="group_$id_attribute_group"}
                                        
                                            {if ($group.group_type == 'select')}
                                                
                                                    {foreach from=$group.attributes key=id_attribute item=group_attribute}
                                                        {$group_attribute|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}
                                                    {/foreach}
                                                
                                            {elseif ($group.group_type == 'color')}
                                                
                                                    {assign var="default_colorpicker" value=""}
                                                    {foreach from=$group.attributes key=id_attribute item=group_attribute}
                                                        {assign var='img_color_exists' value=file_exists($col_img_dir|cat:$id_attribute|cat:'.jpg')}
                                                        
                                                            getProductLink($product)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" id="color_{$id_attribute|intval}" name="{$colors.$id_attribute.name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" class="color_pick{if ($group.default == $id_attribute)} selected{/if}"{if !$img_color_exists && isset($colors.$id_attribute.value) && $colors.$id_attribute.value} style="background:{$colors.$id_attribute.value|escape:'html':'UTF-8'};"{/if} title="{$colors.$id_attribute.name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">
                                                                {if $img_color_exists}
                                                                    
                                                                {/if}
                                                            
                                                        
                                                        {if ($group.default == $id_attribute)}
                                                            {$default_colorpicker = $id_attribute}
                                                        {/if}
                                                    {/foreach}
                                                
                                                
                                            {elseif ($group.group_type == 'radio')}

  {foreach from=$group.attributes key=id_attribute item=group_attribute}
- {$group_attribute|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}
  {/foreach}

{/if}
                                         
                                    
                                {/if}
                            {/foreach}
                         
                    {/if}
                 
                
                    quantity <= 0) || !$product->available_for_order || (isset($restricted_country_mode) && $restricted_country_mode) || $PS_CATALOG_MODE} class="unvisible"{/if}>
                        
                            {if $content_only && (isset($product->customization_required) && $product->customization_required)}
                                
                                    {l s='Customize'}
                                
                            {else}
                                
                                    {l s='Add to cart'}
                                
                            {/if}
                        
                    
                    {if isset($HOOK_PRODUCT_ACTIONS) && $HOOK_PRODUCT_ACTIONS}{$HOOK_PRODUCT_ACTIONS}{/if}
                 
             
        
        {/if}
     
    
 
{if !$content_only}

```
{if (isset($quantity_discounts) && count($quantity_discounts) > 0)}
    <!-- quantity discount -->
    <section class="page-product-box">
        <h3 class="page-product-heading">{l s='Volume discounts'}</h3>
        <div id="quantityDiscount">
            <table class="std table-product-discounts">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>{l s='Quantity'}</th>
                        <th>{if $display_discount_price}{l s='Price'}{else}{l s='Discount'}{/if}</th>
                        <th>{l s='You Save'}</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {foreach from=$quantity_discounts item='quantity_discount' name='quantity_discounts'}
                    <tr id="quantityDiscount_{$quantity_discount.id_product_attribute}" class="quantityDiscount_{$quantity_discount.id_product_attribute}" data-discount-type="{$quantity_discount.reduction_type}" data-discount="{$quantity_discount.real_value|floatval}" data-discount-quantity="{$quantity_discount.quantity|intval}">
                        <td>
                            {$quantity_discount.quantity|intval}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {if $quantity_discount.price >= 0 || $quantity_discount.reduction_type == 'amount'}
                                {if $display_discount_price}
                                    {convertPrice price=$productPrice-$quantity_discount.real_value|floatval}
                                {else}
                                    {convertPrice price=$quantity_discount.real_value|floatval}
                                {/if}
                            {else}
                                {if $display_discount_price}
                                    {convertPrice price = $productPrice-($productPrice*$quantity_discount.reduction)|floatval}
                                {else}
                                    {$quantity_discount.real_value|floatval}%
                                {/if}
                            {/if}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <span>{l s='Up to'}</span>
                            {if $quantity_discount.price >= 0 || $quantity_discount.reduction_type == 'amount'}
                                {$discountPrice=$productPrice-$quantity_discount.real_value|floatval}
                            {else}
                                {$discountPrice=$productPrice-($productPrice*$quantity_discount.reduction)|floatval}
                            {/if}
                            {$discountPrice=$discountPrice*$quantity_discount.quantity}
                            {$qtyProductPrice = $productPrice*$quantity_discount.quantity}
                            {convertPrice price=$qtyProductPrice-$discountPrice}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    {/foreach}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </section>
{/if}

{if isset($features) && $features}
    <!-- Data sheet -->
    <section class="page-product-box">
        <h3 class="page-product-heading">{l s='Data sheet'}</h3>
        <table class="table-data-sheet">            
            {foreach from=$features item=feature}
            <tr class="{cycle values="odd,even"}">
                {if isset($feature.value)}              
                <td>{$feature.name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}</td>
                <td>{$feature.value|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}</td>
                {/if}
            </tr>
            {/foreach}
        </table>
    </section>
    <!--end Data sheet -->
{/if}
{if $product->description}
    <!-- More info -->
    <section class="page-product-box">
        <h3 class="page-product-heading">{l s='More info'}</h3>{/if}
        {if isset($product) && $product->description}
            <!-- full description -->
            <div  class="rte">{$product->description}</div>
    </section>
    <!--end  More info -->
{/if}

<!--HOOK_PRODUCT_TAB -->
<section class="page-product-box">
    {$HOOK_PRODUCT_TAB}
    {if isset($HOOK_PRODUCT_TAB_CONTENT) && $HOOK_PRODUCT_TAB_CONTENT}{$HOOK_PRODUCT_TAB_CONTENT}{/if}
</section>
<!--end HOOK_PRODUCT_TAB -->

{if isset($accessories) && $accessories}
    <!--Accessories -->
    <section class="page-product-box">
        <h3 class="page-product-heading">{l s='Accessories'}</h3>
        <div class="block products_block accessories-block clearfix">
            <div class="block_content">
                <ul id="bxslider" class="bxslider clearfix">
                    {foreach from=$accessories item=accessory name=accessories_list}
                        {if ($accessory.allow_oosp || $accessory.quantity_all_versions > 0 || $accessory.quantity > 0) && $accessory.available_for_order && !isset($restricted_country_mode)}
                            {assign var='accessoryLink' value=$link->getProductLink($accessory.id_product, $accessory.link_rewrite, $accessory.category)}
                            <li class="item product-box ajax_block_product{if $smarty.foreach.accessories_list.first} first_item{elseif $smarty.foreach.accessories_list.last} last_item{else} item{/if} product_accessories_description">
                                <div class="product_desc">
                                    <a href="{$accessoryLink|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" title="{$accessory.legend|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" class="product-image product_image">
                                        <img class="lazyOwl" src="{$link->getImageLink($accessory.link_rewrite, $accessory.id_image, 'tm_home_default')|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" alt="{$accessory.legend|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" width="{$homeSize.width}" height="{$homeSize.height}"/>
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="block_description">
                                        <a href="{$accessoryLink|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" title="{l s='More'}" class="product_description">
                                            {$accessory.description_short|strip_tags|truncate:25:'...'}
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="s_title_block">
                                    <h5 class="product-name">
                                        <a title="{$accessory.name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" href="{$accessoryLink|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">
                                            {$accessory.name|truncate:20:'...':true|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}
                                        </a>
                                    </h5>
                                    {if $accessory.show_price && !isset($restricted_country_mode) && !$PS_CATALOG_MODE}
                                    <span class="price">
                                        {if $priceDisplay != 1}
                                            {displayWtPrice p=$accessory.price}{else}{displayWtPrice p=$accessory.price_tax_exc}
                                        {/if}
                                    </span>
                                    {/if}
                                </div>
                                <div class="clearfix" style="margin-top:5px">
                                    {if !$PS_CATALOG_MODE && ($accessory.allow_oosp || $accessory.quantity > 0)}
                                        <div class="no-print">
                                            <a class="btn btn-default ajax_add_to_cart_button" href="{$link->getPageLink('cart', true, NULL, "qty=1&amp;id_product={$accessory.id_product|intval}&amp;token={$static_token}&amp;add")|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" data-id-product="{$accessory.id_product|intval}" title="{l s='Add to cart'}">
                                                <span>{l s='Add to cart'}</span>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    {/if}
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        {/if}
                    {/foreach}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </section>
    <!--end Accessories -->
{/if}

{if isset($HOOK_PRODUCT_FOOTER) && $HOOK_PRODUCT_FOOTER}{$HOOK_PRODUCT_FOOTER}{/if}
```

Comment: do you use the default-bootstrap theme ? please show us in your product.tpl the price block

Comment: I use angar theme. The price block is off.

Comment: please show us the code source of product.tpl